# Correct ELIF statement producing a syntax error python 3.6.2

Tags: python

Using an IF, ELIF statement for the user to select a sorting algorithm to sort an inputted list. 
The Elif keeps returning syntax errors but I cannot understand why. As far as i know, it is properly indented, a colon is present and there is nother syntax errors I am aware of.

Code:

```
if response == ("bubble"):
    bubble(numbers)
elif response == ("insertion"):
    insertion(numbers)
elif response == ("merge"):
    merge(numbers)
elif response == ("quick"):
    quick(numbers)
else:
    print("incorrect response")
```

MCVE:

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in input("input your list ").split()]
response = input(what algorithm, ")
    if response == ("bubble"):
        bubble(numbers)
    elif response == ("insertion"):
        insertion(numbers)
    elif response == ("merge"):
        merge(numbers)
    elif response == ("quick"):
        quick(numbers)
    else:
        print("incorrect response")
```

(The rest of my code is just four sorting algorithms which I dont think are relevant, if they are comment and I will edit them in.

Comment: I can execute this code without any syntax error. Post a [mcve].

Comment: show us the error.

Comment: I get a syntax error on the first elif for insertion. Is it possible my code is correct and that Python has a bug trying to execute it?

Comment: It's *technically* possible there's a bug in Python, but realistically - no there isn't. You will either have a syntax error earlier in your code (please post a MCVE as requested above), or you're mixing tabs and spaces in your indents.

Comment: Edited to include MCVE. I have redone my indents and found a few spaces and fixed them, however the same syntax error occured.

Comment: I would like to mention that the program did run as expected with no errors without the IF statement and I just called the individual algorithms with the variable numbers line

Comment: `input(what algorithm, ")` is wrong.

Comment: Python says *much more* than just plain `syntax error`. Please make sure to include all possibly relevant information you have in the question.

Comment: My error message simply said invalid syntax and highlighted the first ELIF to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do indeed have an issue with your indentation. You have most of this code indented one level beyond what it should be. Try this instead:

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in input("input your list ").split()]
response = input(what algorithm, ")
if response == ("bubble"):
    bubble(numbers)
elif response == ("insertion"):
    insertion(numbers)
elif response == ("merge"):
    merge(numbers)
elif response == ("quick"):
    quick(numbers)
else:
    print("incorrect response")
```

Indentation in Python denotes the inside of "blocks" which in many other languages are put between curly braces. Essentially, the rule is (no doubt with some exceptions that I'm glossing over) - always indent after a colon, and unindent again when that "block" (body of a function/loop/class/`if` statement etc.) is finished.

Comment: Yes thank you. Amazing how I can get all the algorithms correctly indented but a simple IF statement incorrect. Thanks again for your help